# You have been there 5 hours, it is a new record!

Tags: present-perfect, present-participles

I have been trying to comprehend the difference between present perfect and present perfect continuous.
So I came up with the situation, I say

---

> "Dude, get out from the toilet, you have been seating there for 5 hours !"

perfect continuous, because I am emphasizing the time , how long?

---

> "Dude, it's going to be a new world record, unless you get out from the toilet, you have seated there for 5 hours [already]"

perfect simple, as i am emphasizing the result/score, how many hours?

---

Are the sentences correct? Is this explanation accurate?

Thanks!

Comment: In the first example, it should be "sitting;" other than that, it's correct. In the second example, it should be "sat."

Comment: Is it me or does "out from the toilet" sound wrong? Surely it's "get out of the toilet" [toilet as a room] or "get off the toilet" ? (or is this a BrE AmE thing?)

Comment: @Smock It's unusual. I would also say *get off the toilet*. Or, not mentioning the toilet, *get out **of the bathroom**, you've been **in there** for five hours.* I believe using *toilet* as the name of a room sounds strange in North America, where it's only used for the device itself. At least that's true in my case. Of course, people can *ask* for the toilet—but (as I've always understood) they mean the device, not the room . . .

Comment: Ah yes, get out of the bathroom. What do you call a room with a toilet but no bath in North America?

Answer (score 1):

Example 1, perfect continuous:

> "Dude, get out from the toilet, you have been *sitting* there for 5
>   hours!"

Example 2, perfect simple:

> "Dude, unless you get out from the toilet, it's going to be a new
>   world record; you have *sat* there for 5 hours [already]."

Comment: So are my sentences correct, i mean tense, I've just screwed up with the "seat" and "sit".

Comment: In your second example, you need to properly use sit in present perfect, which is "sat", not "sitted." Also, I'm not sure if the word order in that sentence is correct; I used different word order in my example.